# How to getconf CLK_TCK on Android

Tags: android, unix

How do I access the clock speed (CLK_TCK) on Android using adb shell. On ubuntu thats rather easy:

```
$ getconf CLK_TCK
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android number of clock ticks \[Hertz\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671744/android-number-of-clock-ticks-hertz)