# What is exactly a "Clock Tick" in the context of Android CPU Usage?

Tags: android, linux, cpu, cpu-usage

I am currently working on a project in Android. I want to get the total cpu usage of each and every process. So i am using the contents of "/proc/pid/stat". I referred [this answer to get the stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat). Now i got all the utime, stime etc., The problem is with the value of "Hertz". 
The answer says that it is the number of clock ticks per second. I don't get the exact meaning of clock tick even after browsing a lot. What is a clock tick and is it the frequency of the processor? And the answer says that we can get the clock ticks using

> sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)

I don't know how to use this linux command in Android to get the clock ticks. I have googled it and i couldn't find it. Pls help me with this. And it would be more helpful if there is an example for this clock tick.

Comment: Please check this answer http://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick

Comment: Is it true that in a linux system, ticks occur approximately 100 times per second? i.e., 100 clock ticks per second is usual?

Comment: It depnds on the Hertez set in kernel confiiguration.

Comment: This might help you to understand better http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100 is the default value set on Linux. And it appears to be unchanged in Android as shown in the `sysconf.c` source file - [goo.gl/C5yubg](http://goo.gl/C5yubg)

If you see line 167, this is what `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` will retrun:

`case _SC_CLK_TCK:           return SYSTEM_CLK_TCK;`

The default value for `SYSTEM_CLK_TCK` is defined as `100`